# unrecognized selector sent to instance error when switching between pages in objective c

Tags: iphone

I have a windows based iphone application. I have tabs and from one of the tabs I want to switch another page and display facebook in webview in that page. I get unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

Here is my code where I am trying to do switch:

```
-(IBAction)goFacebookPage:(id)sender
{
    FacebookPage *fbController = [[FacebookPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"FacebookPage" bundle:nil];
    fbController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:fbController animated:YES];
    [fbController release];
}
```

### Traceback is:

```
2012-03-02 15:29:13.797 TPFApp[2344:b903] -[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6818540
2012-03-02 15:29:13.868 TPFApp[2344:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6818540'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f16313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc40bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d33966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d33522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x000144fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x000a4799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000a6c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x000a57d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x00038ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x00019c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x0001ef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffb992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00da3944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d03cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x00022c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  TPFApp                              0x00001e19 main + 121
    22  TPFApp                              0x00001d95 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

### The error message:

```
-[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894210 2012-03-01 21:10:53.218 TPFApp[1750:b903] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894210'
```

Thanks

Comment: This is insufficient information for anyone to know what exactly is causing that crash. What is the selector, and what instance?

Comment: You called "goFacebookPage" passing it a UIViewController.  You should be passing an instance of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Interface Builder you have connected the control (e.g. `UIButton`?) to the View Controller.  However, you haven't set the type of the View Controller to your custom view controller, and instead have connected it to a default instance of `UIViewController`.

To fix this, you need to change the type of your View Controller to the class of your Custom View Controller (the class where you define the `goFacebookPage:` method.  You can do this in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder - see here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that whatever selector (function) is named in the message is being "sent" to the wrong type of object.

Had you even included the barest bit of additional information (such as a copy of the complete message) we'd be able to offer more advice.

Comment: -[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894210
2012-03-01 21:10:53.218 TPFApp[1750:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController goFacebookPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894210'

Comment: @user1244069 -- Wasn't there a traceback??

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your message. I am new here. I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find the class you are calling **`goFacebookPage:`** and make sure that exists in the same class from which you are calling it from.

Comment: Thats fine, but in your implementation that you are calling from, make sure that what you are calling exists.